# Concatenation issue

Tags: c++

I want to take three user input values A, B, C and then create a new integer that stores these three values called capacity. I want the integers to be seperated by a comma but when I output the integer capacity it returns only as the value of C. I don't know how to fix this issue.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A;
    cout <<"Enter Capacity of Jug A"<< endl;
    cin >>A;
    int B;
    cout <<"Enter Capacity of Jug B"<< endl;
    cin >>B;
    int C;
    cout <<"Enter Capacity of Jug C"<< endl;
    cin >>C;

    int capacity;
    capacity = (A, B, C);
    cout <<"capacity is "<< capacity;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basically, you can't do that. Where are you learning C++ from?

Comment: `(A, B, C)` that comma notation doesn't do what you think it does. :-)

Comment: so how can i fix it?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make capacity an array of your numbers right? In that case you need to declare capacity as an array, then you can reference each item with capacity[0] and so on

Comment: Your requirements are impossible.  You said you want to create a "new integer that stores these three values".  An integer can only store one value.  An array of integers could store three values in it.  (If you told us that the three jug capacities had some limit to their size then maybe you could pack the three values into different bits of one integer, but that seems unlikely to be what you're going for.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use array like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A;
    cout << "Enter Capacity of Jug A" << endl;
    cin >> A;

    int B;
    cout << "Enter Capacity of Jug B" << endl;
    cin >> B;

    int C;
    cout << "Enter Capacity of Jug C" << endl;
    cin >> C;

    int capacity[3];
    capacity[0] = A;
    capacity[1] = B;
    capacity[2] = C;

    cout << "capacity is " << capacity[0] << "," << capacity[1] << "," << capacity[2];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate really appreciate it

Comment: recommend `std::array`

Answer (score 0):

one solution to your problem would be creating an array of `int` values. On each position of the array an `int` value is stored.

```
int capacity[3];
cin >> capacity[0];
cin >> capacity[1];
cin >> capacity[2];
cout << capacity[0] << ", " << capacity[1] << ", " << capacity[2] << endl;
```

However, a better way to do this is using a loop. `for`, for example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i)
    {
        cout <<"Enter Capacity of Jug "<< i << endl;
        cin >> capacity[i];
    }
```

And the same way for printing.

More info on arrays: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_arrays.htm
More info on the `for` loop: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm

Answer (score 0):

> I want the integers to be seperated by a comma but when I output the integer capacity it returns only as the value of C.

It is unrealistic to have that with `int capacity;`. `int` can only hold numeric, integral values (within a certain range).

You've titled your question with **Concatenation issue** which makes me believe you're looking for an `std::string` to hold a string value. **Then** you can separate your integers by commas with string literals.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    // std::string

int main()
{
    // ... omitted for brevity

    // use std::string, and CONCATENATE using the + operator
    std::string capacity = "(" + std::to_string(A) + ", " + std::to_string(B) + ", " + std::to_string(C) + ")";

    // ... do something with `capacity` ?

    std::cout << "capacity is " << capacity << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Man, that's a lot. Unless you're planning on using the string for other purposes, you should output your values directly using `std::cout` (as in [Bolov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53685176/10239789)) or use an `std::stringstream` if you like.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // ... omitted for brevity

    std::cout << "capacity is (" << A << ", " << B << ", " << C << ")\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this code, as:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A;
    cout << "Enter Capacity of Jug A" << endl;
    cin >> A;

    int B;
    cout << "Enter Capacity of Jug B" << endl;
    cin >> B;

    int C;
    cout << "Enter Capacity of Jug C" << endl;
    cin >> C;

    cout << "capacity is " << A << "," << B << "," << C << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**What's wrong?**

You simply cannot store three `int` values in one `int` variable. This doesn't make sense. You need other data types to store those values which I explain later.

**What's happening?**

When you separate values by `,` in a right-hand side expression, the compiler sees them as multiple expressions (*expr1*, *expr2*, etc.) and evaluates them in order, but returns the last result (that is the value of `C` in your code). So, there's no surprise that `capacity` always equals `C`.

**What is the right solution?**

There are various ways to solve this problem.

*Use* `struct`

You can define an struct and store the values as its fields:

```
struct caps {
    int A, B, C;
};

caps c = { A, B, C };
```

*Use* `std::array` (since C++11)

```
std::array<int, 3> c = { A, B, C };
```

*Use* `std::tuple` (since C++11)

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> c = std::make_tuple(A, B, C);
```